# What is a good objective function for finding a location "closest" to two other places?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, graph-algorithm, nonlinear-optimization

I have tried to find an answer by googling, but I couldn't make any real progress there (possibly because I didn't know what exactly to google).

The problem I want to solve is something like this: suppose I stay at a location A and my friend stays at a location B. We want to find a restaurant that wouldn't be "too far" for either of us. What would be a good objective function that considers only the restaurant's distances from A and B and captures some notion of "fairness" so that on minimizing the function over the set of possible restaurants, we get to place that isn't unfairly far (or close) for only one person.

I considered the sum of distances, but this gives the same result for all the points on the line joining A and B. Intuitively, it seems that a "fair" function should give a lower value for points near the midpoint. I then considered the sum of squares of distances, but I am not sure this is a very good idea.

Another possibility was considering the distance to the restaurant from the midpoint, but this has some practical problems. Due to various other reasons (like one-way roads, closed roads around the midpoint,  etc.) we might get a bad solution if we just consider the distances from the midpoint. This is the reason I want the objective function to take in only the distances from A and B as inputs (not from any other point).

Comment: You seem to want a function which penalises (large) differences in the distance that you and your friend have to travel, so why not start with just that and fiddle around until you get something that appeals.  As to your fundamental question *What would be a good objective function* that's not really a programming question and is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with so many things in life, worrying about "fairness" leads to suboptimal solutions.

I suggest that the best solution is to minimize **MAX( dist(A) , dist(B) )**

This will be "unfair" if the closest restaurant to **B** is much closer to **A**, but do you really want to pick one that is further away from both parties just to make sure that **A** pays his "fair" share of aggravation?

In case there are several restaurants with the same score, I suggest minimizing **MIN( dist(A), dist(B) )** to break ties, because that prefers smaller total aggravation over larger.  That means that if **B** has to go further, but there are two candidates the same distance away from **B**, then **B** should pick the one that's *closest* to **A**.  After all, **A** and **B** are supposed to be friends, right?  You would be pretty peeved if your friend wanted you to suffer just because their suffering was inescapable.  (I'm sure we all have a *former* friend like that :-)

Note that minimizing the sum of squares, and minimizing the maximum, are both instances of "p-norms" with different exponents:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm

Sum of squares is the L_2 norm, which prefers solutions that are better on average with worse individual components, while minimizing the maximum is the L_infinity norm, which is dominated entirely by the worst individual component.

I think all of the p-norms are reasonable answers to your question.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article, sum of squares is technically the _square of_ L\_2 norm, but this shouldn't affect the minimization problem. (Just to clarify, *(dist(A), dist(B))* is the vector whose norms we are considering here).

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
 objective function = A + B + lambda * abs( A - B )
```

by tuning lambda you can control the weighting given to fairness.

Comment: This is another useful objective function along with Matt Timmermans' suggestion. Is there any reason to prefer this over let us say, `A^2 + B^2 + lambda * (A - B)^2`?

Comment: One potential reason is that A+B is the total distance so will give a good estimate for the actual travelling cost (in terms of either time or money)